# Call event in Excel VBA when switching to another app

Tags: events, excel, vba

I'm looking for an event which gets called when the user switches to another app (without closing Excel) and when he switches back to Excel again. I need to know this to stop a timer triggered event which isn't necessary when app isn't active or nothing is changed.

I would use it to implement an autosave-method which shouldn't save the file if its in the background and therefore not been changed.

Comment: I am fairly sure you will need API for this, which could possibly run in your timer event. There are some [notes here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659457/forms-gotfocus-event-does-not-seem-to-fire/4659751#4659751), which may give you something to play with.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent article on how to find what events are available here
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx
"Open the Object Browser in the VBA Editor (press F2 or choose Object Browser from the View menu. In the Classes list, scroll down and select Worksheet. Right-click anywhere in the primary window and choose Group Members on the pop up menu. Then scroll down in the Members Of "Worksheet" list until you see items with yellow lightening bolts next to them. These are the events for the Worksheet objects. Do the same for the Workbook and Application objects."

Comment: Thanks! Tried those events but I just get Excel to call a sub when moving between Excel workbooks and not between excel and other applications...

Comment: the closest would seem to be Application.WindowActivate but googling just seems to find people not getting it to work.  Sorry

Comment: Thinking about this a little more - I think you'd need to run a monitor program which would check the state of open windows and watch what state the excel window was in.  If you google "enumwindows alt-tab" you'll find a lot of discussion about ways of enumerating the windows.  I'd give a sample of using enumwindows with enumproc but my ocde wouldn't be helpful as it's littered with some extra code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you will be able to find EXCEL events that capture your needs, as jumping to another application is not an EXCEL mechanism, but a general Windows mechanism. In fact you try to capture a kind of "LostFocus" event of the Excel application itself. Excel however gives you only event triggers for events that are "local to the Excel application".

What about calling your external program by pressing an Excel Button which contains code to

- set a global status variable to "I JUMPED OFF"
- stop the timer
- start the external application (Shell or similar), minimize the window or whatever

plus a global Selection_Change trigger that

- examines the status variable, and if it was set to "I JUMPED OFF"
- set it back to "I AM HERE"
- restart the timer

Of course this is a bit weak and the user can trick you out by simply manoevering with the mouse or Alt-TAB, but if you maximize the window on Startup you can motivate the user to use the Buttons.

Comment: My Excel file consists of 8 worksheets, each already stuffed with buttons. I can't add another, which (for the view of the user) just leaves or hides the workbook. They won't use it and then it won't work. I need any solution which triggers an event when leaving excel or which can check if excel is active or give my the active application (which I could run within my timer method before I fire up the actual timer-method)...