# Minimize UserForm when macro in it is running

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to minimize a `Userform` when it is running a method in it. Functionality in my method is so huge that it is running for long time. I would like to minimize `UserForm` so that I could work on some other excel sheets and later come back to `UserForm` (or restore it) during this run.

When `UserForm` is running, it is not allowing to access any of its components(so that even if i add minimize button its of no use). I am able to access other excels and work on them because i have made `Userform` as `vbmodeless`, but my requirement is `userform` should be minimized, now I am dragging `UserForm` to the end of the screen to view other files easily.

Comment: i would suggest using `UserForm.Hide` method instead...

Comment: Thanks KazJaw for your reply. But what if i want to get back to my macro, how do you i know that my macro has completed processing.

Answer (score 4):

Why not add a minimize / maximize to your userform ;)

Here is something from my database (**Not my Code**). Paste this in the userform

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Const WS_MINIMIZEBOX As Long = &H20000
Private Const WS_MAXIMIZEBOX As Long = &H10000
Private Const GWL_STYLE As Long = (-16)
Private Const WS_SYSMENU As Long = &H80000
Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim Ret As Long, styl As Long
    Ret = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption)

    styl = GetWindowLong(Ret, GWL_STYLE)
    styl = styl Or WS_SYSMENU
    styl = styl Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX
    styl = styl Or WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
    SetWindowLong Ret, GWL_STYLE, (styl)

    DrawMenuBar Ret
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: + 1 Nice one. Goes into my collection as well :P

Comment: Wow Really, this worked superbly. Thank so much Siddharth Rout.

Comment: But Sidharth, my question is: if i add minimize button i am not able to access it when macro is running, every object in userform is locked, so i am able to minimize only any of the transaction in userform is completed. Do we have any solution for this.

Comment: Yes it worked:).. Thank you for all your repsonses. Really usefull.