# Excel VBA - return focus to worksheet after UserForm Button click

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a UserForm with a button that alters the font of the selected cell on the active, visible worksheet.

When I click the button, I want the underlying VBA to execute, and then for focus to move back to the selected cell.

Right now, focus remains with the UserForm, so it requires an extra mouse click on the target cell to resume editing the cell content.

I've tried adding ActiveSheet.Activate and ActiveCell.Activate at the end of the button VBA routine; no joy.

How might I get the original ActiveCell to have focus after the UserForm button click?

Comment: Can you show the code

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042521/set-focus-back-to-the-application-window-after-showing-userform

Comment: padawan0007's link does part of the job.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to think about.

a) is your form modal or modeless

b) on the button click do you want to hide the form or keep it visible?

c) am assuming you want to edit the selected cell, if so you need it to go into edit mode with

```
SendKeys "{F2}"
```

Comment: padawan0007's link [ AppActivate Application.Caption ] plus [ SendKeys "{F2}" ] does it.