# Detecting Lost Focus in Excel Application, Workbook or Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Switching to another application via the system `ALT-Tab` hotkey, while working in MS Excel on MS-Windows causes Excel to lose the keyboard focus.  How to detect this?

The `Deactivate` or `WindowDeactivate` events for the objects: `Application` or `Workbook` or `Worksheet` objects do not fire when MS Excel loses focus this way (*of course, because losing the focus is not synonymous with Deactivating the window*)

Comment: This cannot be done using standard Excel functionality. Any of Excel events could not catch losing or getting focus. But it can be done using API. `SetWinEventHook` would be able to do that. I have (somewhere in my computer) such a code. I am  not its 'father', I collected it from somewhere on the net. If I will find it, I will post an answer to show you how I used it... I repeat, I did not create the code in discussion!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, please. I found it somewhere to the internet, three years ago and only adapted to serve my needs. For instance, it could not be stopped because of a wrong declaration of `UnhookWinEvent` API. Take care to not monitor the focus lost or got by using a MsgBox. In this way, pressing 'OK' the focus will be received again and you will be in an infinite loop. The focus status will be returned in the active sheet, range "A1" (received focus), respectively, "A2" (lost focus):

1. Copy the next code on top of a module (in the declarations area):

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Private Const EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND = &H3&
    Private Const WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT = 0
    
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWinEventHook Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal eventMin As Long, _
                ByVal eventMax As Long, ByVal hmodWinEventProc As LongLong, ByVal pfnWinEventProc As LongLong, _
                ByVal idProcess As Long, ByVal idThread As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
                
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWinEvent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWinEventHook As Long) As Long
    
    Private handlColl As Collection
```

2. Copy the next code inside the module:

```
    Public Sub StartMonitoring() 'it can be called from a Workbook/Worksheet event
        StartFocusMonitoring
    End Sub
    
    Public Function StartFocusMonitoring() As Long
      If handlColl Is Nothing Then Set handlColl = New Collection
      StartFocusMonitoring = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 0&, _
                                        AddressOf WinEventFunc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT)
      handlColl.aDD StartFocusMonitoring
    End Function
    
    Public Sub StopEventHook(lHook As Long)
      Dim LRet As Long
      If lHook = 0 Then Exit Sub`
   
      LRet = UnhookWinEvent(lHook)
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub StopMonitoring() 'it must be called manualy or by an event when need to stop monitoring...
      'it did not work until I changed the StopEventHook declaration, using ByVal instead of ByRef
      Dim vHook As Variant, lHook As Long
      For Each vHook In handlColl
        lHook = vHook
        StopEventHook lHook
      Next vHook
    End Sub
    
    Public Function WinEventFunc(ByVal HookHandle As Long, ByVal LEvent As Long, _
                            ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal idObject As Long, ByVal idChild As Long, _
                            ByVal idEventThread As Long, ByVal dwmsEventTime As Long) As Long
      'In case of an error the application will crush. So, bypassing the error is good to be done...`
      On Error Resume Next
      Dim thePID As Long`
    
      If LEvent = EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND Then
        GetWindowThreadProcessId hWnd, thePID
        If thePID = GetCurrentProcessId Then
          'Do not use here a MsgBox, because after pressing OK Excel application
          'will receive focus and you will stay in an infinite loop...
          Application.OnTime Now, "Event_GotFocus"
        Else
          Application.OnTime Now, "Event_LostFocus"
        End If
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
    
    Public Sub Event_GotFocus()
        Range("a1").value = "Received Focus"
        Range("a2").value = ""
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub Event_LostFocus()
       Range("a2").value = "Lost focus"
       Range("a1").value = ""
    End Sub
```

You must start monitoring from `StartMonitoring` `Sub` which can be called directly or through an event (Workbook_Open, for instance).

The monitoring can be stopped calling `StopMonitoring` `Sub`...